# How to Use OrderBy in linq for DataTable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have two Data table Folder_table and folder_filter. Both the table has two columns `FolderName` and `FolderDateTime` . In the Folder_Table i have values like below

```
FolderName   FolderDateTime

Test1        29/3/2014
Test2        20/12/2014
Test3        4/2/2014
test5        9/6/2014
```

I am using the below coding to copy 2 rows from Folder_table to folder_filter

```
folder_filter = Folder_table.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(2).CopyToDataTable();
```

I want to order by descending in `FolderDateTime` column. how to do that. PLease help

Comment: Try the cunningly named `.OrderByDescending()` method?

Comment: I used this way                             folder_filter = Folder_table.Clone();                         
                            DataRow[] results = Folder_table.Select("1=1", "FolderDateTime DESC");                            
                            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                                folder_filter.ImportRow(results[i]); now it works.. thank you

Answer (score 17):

If your field data type is `DateTime` then you can use:

```
var sortedTable = Folder_table.AsEnumerable()
                 .OrderBy(r => r.Field<DateTime>("FolderDateTime"))
                 .CopyToDataTable();
```

If your column type is `string` then first you have to parse these values to `DateTime` type object. Use `DateTime.ParseExact` with format `d\M\yyyy` like:

```
var sortedTable = Folder_table.AsEnumerable()
                 .OrderBy(r => DateTime.ParseExact(r.Field<string>("FolderDateTime"),
                                                    "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                 .CopyToDataTable();
```

You should see: [LINQ to DataSet/ DataTable - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
var sortTable = Folder_table.AsQueryable().OrderBy(r => r.FolderDataTime).ToList();
```

Comment: It shows me error saying 'Specified cast not valid'